# Visual Studio Emulator for android gets stuck on "Creating a system restore point"

Tags: android, api, visual-studio-2015, restore-points

I have tried severally installing visual studio emulator for android, but it gets stuck on "Creating system restore point". Similarly, it does not acquire past "API 19". I have even left it overnight. What should I do?

This is my screenshot:

[image]